# Multiple folders are created while using google drive api

Tags: java, concurrency, google-drive-api

I have the following class which should created **Site-1** folder if it doesn't exist and create subfolder under it.  What I observed under multithreaded environment that it creates multiple **"Site-1"** folder. Somehow the query to find the folder is not returning the expected result.  I have made the class as Singleton and put all call to google drive in one synchronized method.  Still is behaving unexpectedly.  Do you have any suggestions to correct this?

````
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportGoogleDriveUploader.class);
    private static final String FOLDER_MIME_TYPE = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
    private static final DateTimeFormatter IQVIA_TIMESTAMP =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss-SSSXXX");
    private static final String GOOGLE_IQVIA_PDF_KEY = "%s-%s.pdf";
    private static final String GOOGLE_IQVIA_CSV_KEY = "%s-%s.csv";
    private static final String PDF_MIME_TYPE = "application/pdf";
    private final String iqviaGoogleDrive;
    private final Drive googleDriveClient;

    @Inject
    @Singleton
    public ReportGoogleDriveUploader(final String iqviaGoogleDrive, final Drive googleDriveClient) {
        this.iqviaGoogleDrive = iqviaGoogleDrive;
        this.googleDriveClient = googleDriveClient;
    }

    public synchronized void upload(
        final GenerateWaveformPdfEvent event,
        final PresentedWaveformPdfParams params,
        final byte[] pdfRawBytes,
        final IqviaWhoopUser iqviaWhoopUser
    ) throws IOException {
        final int userId = event.getUserId();
        final OffsetDateTime startTime =
            OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(params.getStartTime()), ZoneOffset.UTC);
        final String iqviaStart = startTime.format(IQVIA_TIMESTAMP);
        final String iqviaWhoopId = iqviaWhoopUser.getIqviaUserId();

        /* get user folder */
        String[] pathList = {"site-1", iqviaWhoopId};

        String folderId = iqviaGoogleDrive;
        for (String folder : pathList) {
            String query =
                "'" + folderId + "' in parents and name='" + folder
                    + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false";
            final Drive.Files.List request = googleDriveClient.files().list().setQ(query);
            FileList files = request.execute();
            if (files.getFiles().isEmpty()) {
                final File fileMetadata = new File();
                fileMetadata.setName(folder);
                fileMetadata.setMimeType(FOLDER_MIME_TYPE);
                fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));
                final File createdFolder = googleDriveClient.files().create(fileMetadata).execute();
                folderId = createdFolder.getId();
            } else {
                folderId = files.getFiles().get(0).getId();
            }
        }

        final List<String> parents = new ArrayList<>();
        parents.add(folderId);

        // write the PDF file
        final String iqviaGooglePdfKey = String.format(GOOGLE_IQVIA_PDF_KEY, iqviaWhoopId, iqviaStart);
        final File pdfFileMetadata = new File();
        pdfFileMetadata.setName(iqviaGooglePdfKey);
        pdfFileMetadata.setParents(parents);
        pdfFileMetadata.setMimeType(PDF_MIME_TYPE);

        googleDriveClient.files()
            .create(pdfFileMetadata, new InputStreamContent(PDF_MIME_TYPE, new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfRawBytes)))
            .execute();

        // write the csv file
        final String iqviaGoogleCsvKey = String.format(GOOGLE_IQVIA_CSV_KEY, iqviaWhoopId, iqviaStart);
        String csvContent =
            iqviaWhoopId + "," + iqviaStart + "," + params.getAverageHeartRate() + "," + params.getDetermination();

        final File csvFileMetadata = new File();
        csvFileMetadata.setName(iqviaGoogleCsvKey);
        csvFileMetadata.setParents(parents);
        csvFileMetadata.setMimeType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        googleDriveClient.files()
            .create(
                csvFileMetadata,
                new InputStreamContent(
                    MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN,
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(csvContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                )
            )
            .execute();
    }
}```
````